# Haskell linear algebra libraries that are polymorphic with classes of kind *

Tags: haskell, linear-algebra, applicative

I want to use a linear algebra library with netwire. Because netwire's types are instances of `Applicative`, it provides `Num` and `Fractional` instances for its types that automagically `liftA2` the appropriate function. This is nice because you can do things like multiply time-varying values without any extra effort.

I've been using linear, but its functions are defined to be polymorphic over a non-`*` kind, ie the matrix product:

```
(!*!) :: (Functor m, Foldable t, Additive t, Additive n, Num a)
    => m (t a) -> t (n a) -> m (n a)
```

This means, if I am not much mistaken, that I can't define instances for `Additive` and company, because there is no sane form for the instance to take. While I can write

```
instance Num b => Num (Wire s e m a b) where ...
```

there is no way to write

```
instance Additive n => Additive (Wire s e m a (n x)) where ...
```

because `(Wire s e m a (n x))` has the wrong kind (`*` as opposed to `* -> *`). Other libraries I've seen aren't polymorphic at all.

What I want to know is, which linear algebra libraries are polymorphic over kind `*`?

I've looked at Vec, which seems better. Its matrix multiply has type

```
(Map v v' m1 m3, Map v a b v', Transpose m2 b, Fold v a, Num v, Num a)
    => m1 -> m2 -> m3
```

which is what I want. Are there other libraries like this?

Comment: You could use `newtype WireP n x = WireP (Wire (n x))`, then instance `Additive (Wire n)`.  The newtype wrapping/unwrapping could be a pain though.

Comment: Doesn't Wire take something like 5 arguments?

Comment: @n.m. It does, I've simplified it a bit because the question isn't really about netwire. The important thing is that a partially applied `Wire` is an `Applicative`.

Comment: I don't quite understand how do you want to use Wire. Do you want `Wire x` (simplified) to form linear space over `x`? If so, why not make the partially-applied `Wire` an instance of `Additive`?

Comment: @n.m. Yes that's what I want. I can't write that instance, however, for the reasons described in the question. I've edited the question to include the actual type of `Wire` to make it clearer.

Comment: The question implies you want to transform `n` (a vector space *constructor*)  into `Wire s e m a (n ?)` another vector space *constructor*. The comment says something else.

Comment: @n.m. Okay, I understand your comment now. I don't want `Wire`s to be a linear space over x. The `Wire` will contain a `Matrix44` or whatever the actual type is.

Comment: Oh okay, so luqui's comment actually makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space), which is indeed in many ways more elegant than the libraries that are parameterised over their scalars (`VectorSpace` has that field instead as an associated type synonym).

Part of what I like about it is that it's totally not based on *free* vector spaces as [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) is, which means a signature based on `Foldables` wouldn't make any sense in the first place. (Indeed, it doesn't talk about matrices at all, only about [linear mappings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.6/docs/Data-LinearMap.html#t%3a%3a-45--42-), which are simply [the morphisms of the category of vector spaces](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/60354d30600edd3263001ff3c4e01e1100782232/examples/VectK.hs))

```
instance (AdditiveGroup a) => AdditiveGroup (Wire a) where
  ...

instance (VectorSpace v) => VectorSpace (Wire v) where
  type Scalar (Wire v) = Scalar v  -- Or perhaps `Wire (Scalar v)`
  ...
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning free vector spaces. I didn't know that concept had a name, and now my question makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Aren't all vector spaces free? (Did you mean "free module"?)

Comment: @n.m.: all finite-(or even countably-)dimensional vectorspaces are _isomorphic_ to a free vector space, but **a)** sometimes it's interesting to work with Hilbert spaces that don't even have a basis **b)** being isomorphic to something doesn't mean it's a good idea to always exploit it... in Haskell, we don't use tuples all the time either, when it's more descriptive to introduce an isomorphic `data` type!

Comment: Fair enough, but then Additive doesn't describe vector spaces that are necessarily "naturally" free ((x->) for example can be made Additive).

Comment: @n.m.: actually, `(x -> a)` is the _archetypical_ free vector space spanned by `a` over the type `x`. (It was a bit stupid what I said above, because the space of all functions e.g. ℝ -> ℝ is of course _over-countably_ infinite-dimensional.) But indeed function spaces are a typical example for spaces where you can't use a basis, for instance [the space of continous function has no ("reasonable") basis](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/151159/11107).

Comment: Anyway, my reservations about the `* -> *` kind is actually more for conceptual, rather than practical reasons. The real physical space (or, what we think it is) sure has a perfectly fine, even finite, basis. Yet this basis is not given by nature in any way, but chosen completely arbitrary. If you treat it like a free vector space you constantly need to account for this fact and talk about gauge freedom and strange transformation behaviour all the time (indeed, that's a big chunk of the problems physicists are dealing with everydays).

Comment: Oh well. Need to decide what "free" means, "has a basis" or "is a free object in the category of vector spaces" or something else...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49434/discussion-between-leftaroundabout-and-n-m)

Answer (score 1):

I did a survey of some other libraries, and here's what I found:

- hmatrix - actively maintained; classes of kind `* -> *`, GPL licensed
- vect - OpenGL bindings; not actively maintained; uses hardwired scalar types so things like `dot` can't be lifted
- Vec - sort of actively maintained; not overloaded correctly (see below); useful auxiliary functions; no OpenGL bindings
- linear - actively maintained; supported by GLUtil and vinyl-gl; `* -> *` classes
- vector-space - sort of actively maintained; overloaded correctly; OpenGL bindings, but for vectors only; after an hour I still can't figure out how to use it, especially the linear mappings
- Tensor - built into OpenGL; no math functions
- bed-and-breakfast - actively maintained; uses unboxed arrays; uses type families on value type, so it could be overloaded but it would look weird (ie `Matrix (Wire s e m a Double)` is a wire carrying matricies); no OpenGL interface

This eliminates all but Vec, vector-space, and bed-and-breakfast. The wonky types eliminate bed-and-breakfast (unfortunately, because it's otherwise nice). In the end Vec ends up winning just a little over vector-space because it seems to be designed for graphics rather than abstract algebra study. And because I can't seem to figure out how to make a perspective transformation with linear maps.

I'll have to write an OpenGL interface (which shouldn't be too bad since it's already `Storable`). The only downside is that I can't think of a sensible typeclass for dimension-dependent arguments/results of auxiliary functions (ie `rotationX :: Floating a => a -> Mat44 a`). This is one of the strengths of vector-space I lose with Vec.

Update: Vec will not work. The classes aren't just for result types, they are on types that get put into the vector as well. For instance, the `Fold` class.

Final update: I ended up giving up on this idea and creating separate functions for `Wire`s.